# Connection Refused with cocoon-cordova-labs-local-webserver

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using [cocoon-cordova-labs-local-webserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cocoon-cordova-labs-local-webserver).

Here's the whole `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.app.app" version="6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Name</name>
    <author email="marktsang10@hotmail.com" href="http://dscova.com">The Dscova Team</author>
    <content src="http://localhost:49000" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file parent="ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption" target="*-Info.plist">
            <false />
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-custom-config" spec="~3.1.2" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.3.1" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.1.2" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="~4.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cocoon-cordova-labs-local-webserver" spec="~2.4.1" />
</widget>
```

I also have this in the html head:

```
  <meta
    http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="
      default-src 'self' data: gap:
        http://localhost*
        https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
      style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
      font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
      img-src * 'self' data:;
      media-src *;
    ">
```

[image: app start msg]

Comment: same situation. In my cocoon app

Answer (score 1):

aahhh, i realized that this plugin is only for ios. For android you need to use different plugins.